# Why the boiling point decreases with increase in branching in alkyl groups?

Tags: organic-chemistry, intermolecular-forces

I found out the answer is that

> with increase in branching, the molecules attain a spherical shape with less surface area. As a result, interparticle forces become weaker resulting in lower boiling point.

My problem is that if it attains a spherical shape then how is its surface area less because sphere has the largest surface area?
So please anyone can help me by answering in simple language?

Answer (score 2):

It's not just how much surface area, but, crucially, the *surface area in contact with other molecules*. Bear in mind that we are looking especially at van der Waals' forces here (or London dispersion forces, or instantaneous dipole forces, or whatever other name you have for them).

If you have a lot of long chain molecule together, almost all of their surface area is very near the next molecule. Examine these sausages. See how almost their entire length on the left and right side of each sausage is in contact with the next sausage. Going back to molecules, this represents a large surface over which the intermolecular forces can act.

[image]

On the other hand, branched molecules do not fit as tightly together. See this image (no pun intended)

[image]

Extra branches on the molecules mean that they do not stack as well, so for a given molecule, there is less surface area of that molecule in close contact with another molecule (therefore weaker van der Waals).